# How should I add TabBarView in the below code?

Tags: flutter, tabs, tabbar

I am using below code in which working fine, only thing is that I want to configure the respective views for the sub tabs in the below code in flutter, I have referred this example to create the nested tabs in the below code, I am not able configure the TabBarView() for the same, I just tried and then nothing was visible on the screen.

Please guide me through to resolve this issue

```
Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 32),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          
          Expanded(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
              elevation: 8,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TabBar(
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),

                      ],
                      controller: _tabController,       // Here is the new code added to,
                    ),


                    

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Wrap your `TabbarView` with `Expanded` right after the `TabBar`. `Column` is a `Flex` type widget and `TabbarView` doesn't really know how to set place in its parent. By using `Expanded` you are telling child widget to fill the remaining space on the current context (or screen).

Comment: You're welcome. This issue rise when you are trying to place a widget that has an unbounded size or in other words does not have an explicit size in a `Flex` widget. 
For exampe placing a TextField in a Row, or Column.
You should either set a size explicitly by wrapping it with a `SizedBox` or a `Container`, or you use `Expanded`.